# Magento - override "OnepageController.php"

Tags: magento

I have a problem overriding the controller "OnepageController.php" located in "app \ code \ core \ Mage \ Checkout \ controllers", more exactly on the side of xml configuration file and the tree of my module, I am a bit lost in it ...

A little help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm correct you can just put your class override in *app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php* and it will be used instead of the core class.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want !

Comment: Keep in mind that by placing it in the local area, you now have to keep track of the entire file, so upgrading Magento will be more difficult.

Comment: Yes, most of the time it is probably more useful to extend the class rather than to override this. You might find some useful information in articles like this one: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/174/changing_and_customizing_magento_code